# I keep getting an error saying invalid types int[int] for array subscript

Tags: c++

Sorry if my code is garbage, I just started programming, and I'm sure there are quite a few things I'm doing wrong. Please also let me know on how I can improve this. I'm trying to create a program that checks the password a user enters. Right now I keep getting an invalid types error. Would appreciate any help:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

#define N 20

// Program that checks for a secure password so far
class Password
{
public:
   char UserPassword[N];
   int MenuChoice;
   int Length;
   int LowerCaseAmount = 0;
   int UpperCaseAmount = 0;
   int DigitAmount = 0;
   int SpecialCharAmount = 0;

void Menu()
{
    std::cout << "1. Check my current password \n"
              << "2. Generate me a secure password \n"
              << std::endl;
    std::cin >> MenuChoice;

    if (MenuChoice == 1)
    {
        //
    }
    else if (MenuChoice == 2)
    {
        //
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "INVALID OPTION! ";
    }
}

void CheckPassword()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your current password : \n";
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin >> UserPassword;

    if (strlen(UserPassword) >= 10)
    {
        Length = strlen(UserPassword);
        for (int i=0; i<Length; i++)
        {
            if (Length[i] == 'a' && Length[i] == 'z') ++LowerCaseAmount;
            if (Length[i] == 'A' && Length[i] == 'Z') ++UpperCaseAmount;
            if (Length[i] == '0' && Length[i] == '9') ++DigitAmount;
            if (Length[i] == '!' && Length[i] == '*') ++SpecialCharAmount;
        }

        if (LowerCaseAmount > 0 && UpperCaseAmount > 0 && DigitAmount > 0 && SpecialCharAmount > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Secure! ";
        }
        else if (LowerCaseAmount == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Try adding some lower case letters! ";
        }
        else if (UpperCaseAmount == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Try adding some upper case letters! ";
        }
        else if (DigitAmount == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Try adding some numbers! ";
        }
        else if (SpecialCharAmount == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Try adding some special characters! ForEX : @, $, % ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Password should be ten digits or loner! "
                  << std::endl;
    }
   }
};

int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `Length`? It's mentioned in the error message. What does `Length[i]`, is `int Length` an array?

Comment: UserPassword[i] not Length[i]. Length is an integer.

Comment: @273K Thanks very much! im not sure how i missed that!

Answer (score 1):

```
int Length;
```

You declared an `int` class member called `Length`.

```
if (Length[i] == 'a' && Length[i] == 'z')
```

This is using `Length` as if it was an array (or some container with an `[]` overload). `Length` is not an array. `Length` is just a plain, boring, lonely `int`, see above. This is the reason for your compilation error.

Looking at the overall code, it seems that you should be looking at `userPassword` here, which is your array (or array-like) object.